# Knockout JS, live updating data from websocket

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to load data from a websocket to show on a gauge using knockout and gaugeMeter.js.
I keep getting the "cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element" error.
Here is the code
HTML

```
<div class="GaugeMeter gaugeMeter" id="PreviewGaugeMeter" data-bind="gaugeValue: Percent" data-size=350 data-theme="Orange" data-back="Grey"
  data-text_size="0.4" data-width=38 data-style="Arch" data-animationstep="0" data-stripe="3"></div>
```

JS

```
// Bind new handler to init and update gauges.
      ko.bindingHandlers.gaugeValue = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
            $(element).gaugeMeter({ percent: ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()) });
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
          
            $(element).gaugeMeter({ percent: activePlayerData.boost });
            
        }
      };

      // Create view model with inital gauge value 15mph
      // Use observable for easy update.
      var myViewModel = {
        Percent: ko.observable(15)
      };
      
      ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
```

The activePlayerData.boost is the data I am getting from the websocket and need to update the value, it always shows the first value but everything after that is giving the error.
I am really lost with the knockout stuff as I am very new to coding.

Comment: You need to show what happens when a websocket message arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal, working sample for your use case is below. You can run it to see what it does:

```js
// simple gaugeMeter jQuery plugin mockup
$.fn.gaugeMeter = function (params) {
  return this.css({width: params.percent + '%'}).text(params.percent);
}

// binding handler for that plugin
ko.bindingHandlers.gaugeValue = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var boundValue = valueAccessor();
    var val = ko.unwrap(boundValue); // or: val = boundValue();
    $(element).gaugeMeter({ percent: val });
  }
};

// set up viewmodel
var myViewModel = {
  Percent: ko.observable(15)
};
ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);
  
// simulate regular value updates
setInterval(function () {
  var newPercentValue = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100);
  myViewModel.Percent(newPercentValue);
}, 1500);
```

```css
div.gaugeMeter {
  background-color: green;
  height: 1em;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gaugeMeter" data-bind="gaugeValue: Percent"></div>
```

Things to understand:

- The `update` part of the binding handler is called whenever the bound observable (i.e. `Percent`) changes its value. You don't strictly need the `init` part if there is nothing to initialize.
- The `valueAccessor` gives you the thing that holds the bound value. Typically, but not necessarily this is an observable - like in your case. Once you have called `valueAccessor()`, you still need to open (aka "unwrap") that observable to see what's inside. This is why my code above takes two steps, `valueAccessor()` and `ko.unwrap()`.

  - *When would it ever not be an observable?* - You are free to bind to literal values in your view (`data-bind="gaugeValue: 15"`), or to non-observable viewmodel properties (`data-bind="gaugeValue: basicEfficiency"`) when the viewmodel has `{basicEfficiency: 15}`. In all cases, `valueAccessor()` will give you *that* value, observable or not.
  - *Why use `ko.unwrap(boundValue)` instead of `boundValue()`?* - The former works for both literal values and for observables, the latter only works for observables. In a binding handler it makes sense to support both use cases.
- Once an update arrives, e.g. via WebSocket, don't try to re-apply any bindings or re-initialize anything.

  All you need to do is to change the value of the respective observable in your viewmodel. Changing an observable's value works by calling it: `myViewModel.Percent(15);` would set `myViewModel.Percent` to 15.

  If 15 is different from the previous value, the observable will take care of informing the necessary parties (aka "subscribers"), so all required actions (such as view updates) can happen.